# How to deal with question which is a duplicate of another question on another SE?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/25108/why-do-many-states-in-america-have-straight-borders) is a duplicate of [this question on history SE](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/21217/why-are-the-usa-and-canadas-states-border-so-straight), however the Stack Exchange only allow to flag duplicate for questions on the same Stack Exchange.

Is it considered fine to have two exact same questions on two different SE sites?

Comment: [Yup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/what-to-do-with-cross-site-duplicates)